# Linking form for homology with general coefficients

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology, abelian-groups, pontrjagin-duality

For integral homology groups there is the notion of linking form (http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Linking_form)
$$
Tor(H_{l}(X,\mathbb{Z}))\times Tor(H_{n-l-1}(X,\mathbb{Z}))\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}
$$
for the torsion part of the homology groups. This can be defined by using the Bockstein map associated with the sequence $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Maybe this is a very trivial generalization, but is there an analogous notion for homology groups with coefficients in an arbitrary abelian group $A$? I am looking for something like
$$
Tor(H_{l}(X,A))\times Tor(H_{n-l-1}(X,A^{\vee}))\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}
$$
where $A^{\vee}$ is the dual group. If yes, what is the Bockstein map one should use?

Comment: I would say the pairing is defined purely by Poincare duality, and $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$ comes up via an $Ext$ computation, i.e. the homomorphisms from the torsion subgroup to $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$ is just a concrete model for $Ext$.   For homology with coefficients you would need the corresponding Poincare duality to hold and then identify the appropriate $Ext$ (when applying universal coefficients to relate cohomology with an appropriate dual of homology).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Ryan's comment, one way to get the torsion linking form you mention (at least for compact oriented manifolds) is through the sequence of isomorphisms $$Tor(H_l(X;\mathbb{Z}))\cong Tor(H^{n-l}(X;\mathbb{Z})) \cong Ext(H_{n-l-1}(X);\mathbb{Z})\cong Ext(Tor(H_{n-l-1}(X));\mathbb{Z})\cong Hom(Tor(H_{n-l-1}(X));\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) .$$
The first isomorphism is Poincar'e duality, and the second is the universal coefficient theorem (using that the Ext summand corresponds to the torsion subgroup). The third is a basic property of Ext (write the homology group as a sum of a torsion group and a free group - this uses that the homology is finitely generated from the compactness assumption). The final can be seen to come from the short exact sequence you mention: take the Hom/Ext exact sequence and note that $Ext(-,\mathbb{Q})=0$ always and $Hom(A,\mathbb{Z})=0$ when $A$ is torsion.

So all this can be generalized in circumstances in which these properties all hold. For example, if $R$ is a Dedekind ring and $X$ is a compact $R$-orientable manifold, I believe everything should go through to give a pairing $Tor(H_l(X;R))\otimes Tor(H_{n-l-1}(X;R))\to Q(R)/R$, where $Q(R)$ is the field of quotients of $R$.

Offhand, I'm not sure about a version in which the coefficients are modules over $R$ (in your original question, modules over $\mathbb{Z}$). One would have to think through in what cases versions of these isomorphisms still hold.

*Note: You don't mention manifolds explicitly, but the site you link to for your basic definitions does assume the context of closed, oriented manifolds.

**It does take a little work to show that this definition of the linking form is equivalent to the one using the Bockstein.

Comment: I think if you want to use non-projective modules as your coefficents, you're going to run into problems in general with identifying $Tor(H^{n-l}(X;G))$ with the $Ext$ term of the universal coefficient short exact sequence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you provide a reference for the equivalence with the definition using Bockstein?

Comment: @AndreaAntinucci This is more or less explained in my book Singular Intersection Homology. If you look in the section about torsion pairings, I give an explicit formula for the pairing starting with essentially the definition above. I do it for cohomology but the homology pairing just uses the Poincare duals, which is also the case in the site you link to. I don't explicitly mention the Bockstein, but in that formula the cochain b/t maps to \beta via the Bockstein. This can be seen by thinking through the definition of the Bockstein map via the "zig-zag" definition of the connecting morphism.

Comment: In the book I work in the context of intersection homology, but if your space is a manifold, intersection homology and cohomology are just ordinary singular homology and cohomology, so you can ignore all the intersection homology decorations in the notation.

Comment: Thank you very much!